# How to call a Google Cloud Endpoint from Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-endpoints

How to call a Google Cloud Endpoint from Google Apps Script?

There must be a supported way to do this.

For example, you create an end point and you want to use it from Google Apps Script.  The only thing I see is to use UrlFetchApp.fetch.  But there must be a better way.

Thanks.

Comment: What additional functionality would you be seeking beyond what `UrlFetchApp.fetch` offers?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately UrlFetchApp is the only supported way to call a Google Cloud Endpoints API at the moment. Please see our [support page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#features) for more information on how file a feature request to add better support for Cloud Endpoints.